# How do I let MySQL give me an error when a field is null?

Tags: mysql

How do I create a table with fields that doesn't accept NULL values.

for example a table.

```
create table student
(
   id_no int(3) unsigned primary key,
   fname varchar(30),
   lname varchar(30),
   age
)
```

I want that fname and lname will be never empty and give me an error if I don't fill up anything in it. I've tried adding "Not Null" after the data types but It still accepts the record even if fname is not filled up.

Comment: Add a default value of NULL as well, not just NOT NULL

Comment: Empty is not NULL. You can insert empty, i.e. a zero length string into a `NOT NULL` varchar field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit :**

After a few research and trial, I've come up with a solution. Actually, you are inserting empty strings and they are not NULL. To check for NULL error do:

```
INSERT INTO `student` ( `fname`,`lname`) VALUES ('john',NULL)
```

You will get the error :

```
[Err] 1048 - Column 'lname' cannot be null
```

To prevent empty string either you have to use triggers, or do the checks on server side programming language to convert empty strings to NULL before performing INSERT query. An example trigger for INSERT is like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER avoid_empty_records
    BEFORE INSERT ON student
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF new.fname = '' THEN SET new.fname = NULL ;
END IF;

        IF new.lname = '' THEN SET new.lname = NULL ;
END IF;

END;
```

Now if you try to leave either fname or lname blank, it will show the error below :

```
Column 'lname' cannot be null
```

Comment: That is wrong, he already did that, the issue is the default value of the columns

Comment: "I've tried adding "Not Null" after the data types but It still accepts the record even if fname is not filled up."

Comment: Edited to reflect what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Funny! I fear if the any RDBMS accepts `NULL` as default in to a `NOT NULL` field

Comment: `ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'id_no'`

Comment: @HayderAbbass: So long as the fields are defined `NOT NULL`, *you can't reset any data input, into them* as `NULL` using triggers.

Comment: ok...I see the error when i input the value null...so where do I type in the code above? is it for mysql? or its just a concept so I can make any empty fields = NULL value?

Comment: ohh...I just tried it in mysql after some research on how to create triggers but I get an error message that I can't create multiple triggers something...

Comment: You need to delete the previous trigger before creating another one :
`DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `avoid_empty_records``

Comment: Awesome! Have a great day! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT NULL` prevents `NULL` values, however an empty string is not the same as `NULL`.

To prevent `NULL`, you're doing the right thing adding `NOT NULL`, to prevent empty values you normally use for example a `CHECK` constraint.

The problem is that MySQL does not actually enforce `CHECK` constraints, so in this case you're struck with a trigger, something like;

```
delimiter //
create trigger trg_empty_names before insert on student
for each row
begin
    if new.fname = '' OR new.lname= '' then
        signal sqlstate '45000' 
          set message_text = 'MyError: Trying to insert an empty name';
    end if;
end
//
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eaa72/1).

Comment: so you mean it isn't possible to give me an error?
Maybe I'll just find a another way like doing the error in the PHP part...thanks

Comment: @shadowj3yz: This solution works. It throws an exception when you are trying to insert an empty string into any of the referred fields. You can extend this to other fields if required.

Comment: @shadowj3yz Well, the trigger above _will_ enforce that no empty strings are set as names, however validation logic in the code will usually be able to give better error messages so it may still be a good idea.

Comment: Try the trigger I've wrote in my answer. It will trigger an error if one the the fields is empty.